# Magento 2 - Configurable product with changing page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options

I saw some shops, where customers can choose options with changing product page. See example [here](https://www.sohomod.com/living/sectional-sofas/telus-sectional-w-2-ottomans-brown.html).

[image]

Also, this product was added as simple and we can see them on the category page with the same options.

[image: category page].

Do I need to make some extensions for this? Maybe someone has any solutions? How to show added a configurable product in the category and can they be related?